# npm install doesn't seem to install devDependencies packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I was able to npm install once after clearing the cache in ~/.npm directory, but it just won't work anymore now even after I remove all the cache. It looks like npm just ignore all the devDependencies packages. I am using npm v5.0.3, and tried node v6.9.1 and node v8.1.2 with no luck. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're running `npm install`? `npm install` installs the `devDependencies` unless supplied the `--production` flag.

Comment: yes I am, I believe it has something to do with caching on the global .npm

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your NODE_ENV environment variable? I guess you have NODE_ENV=production. So, npm don't install your devDependency.

For checking:

```
env | grep NODE_ENV
```

For unsetting:

```
unset NODE_ENV
```

Comment: Could you remove `package-lock.json`, `npm-shrinkwrap.json` files and try `npm install`?

Comment: yes, I did that, and undo all the changes npm install did to my package.json, then removed node_modules and redo npm i